# How to implement PUSH Mechanism in Asynchronous Client/Socket programming in JAVA?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple serversocket program ( Both client and server).
Now,for continuous data receive and transfer, I have a while(true){}  (***Infinite Loop***) in both my Client and Server.

---

> **Is there is a way to replace this infinite loop with anything that
>   accepts or sends data when only data is available?**

---

> That means for example, my Client needs to send data to the Sever only
>   when data is available. Similarly my Server needs to receive data only
>   when the Client sends data. This **shouldn't** be implemented in a
>   ***infinite loop*** but has to be ***continuously*** transfer and receive data.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but it sounds a little bit like you want to use [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace your infinite loop with executors Thread that can run periodically.

```
 ScheduledExecutorService execService =  Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
        execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
        new CLASSNAME.startThread();    //Thread();
       }, 0, 5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```